# Configurar connection string para diferentes ambientes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Gostaria de saber se é possível realizar a configuração de uma `connection string` para dois ambientes destintos, por exemplo, o `debug` e o `release`. Ou seja, quando estiver debugando, a `connection string` será uma e a partir do momento que houver a publicação do projeto, ela seja outro. Procurei alguns exemplos, mas não entendi muito bem como implementar.